# adjective & verb form of "fidelity"

Tags: etymology

Can anyone tell me the etymological *root* of the word **"fidelity"** ?
I've found [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fidelitous) the adjective form of it to be **"fidelitous"** (*faithful*). I don't know whether it's correct. And what is the verb of it (i.e *to trust*) ?

Comment: OED gives ***fide** v. rare. [f. L. fīd-ĕre to confide.] trans. To confide or entrust **to***. With 1863 citation *"The‥request that her infant daughter might be **fided to** the care of her friend."* But I think the etymology is General Reference, and that verb form is Too Localised.

Comment: **Fide** (v.) and **Fidelitous** (Adj.) says my teacher too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on  ([Merriam-Webster Online's definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fidelity)), it comes from Latin (by way of French and Middle English): *fides* meaning faith and *fidere* meaning to trust.

Fidelitous is the adjective, although it's not used all that commonly. There's not a verb form that I've seen or can find, and the verb form wouldn't mean "to trust," but "to be faithful."

Answer (score 2):

An English verb phrase along the same lines is **to keep faith**.  There are not many definitions online; [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/keep_faith) says

> (transitive)to continue to have confidence in someone or something, and to support them or it